# NFC Tag lost in ISO dep communication in android(javacard)

Tags: android, tags, nfc, javacard, nexus-s

I am new to NFC development.so i create Android application which send data to jcop(31/36) card and it encrypted Data(key generation) and send back to nexus s device.But every time i got this error.In my java card application i used RSA2048 for data encryption.Can anyone tell me is that problem with java card or android device.(When i try application with galaxy S2 it works fine)

```
08-14 17:20:36.411: D/AudioHardware(89): AudioHardware pcm playback is exiting standby.
08-14 17:20:36.411: D/AudioHardware(89): openPcmOut_l() mPcmOpenCnt: 0
08-14 17:20:36.462: D/NativeNfcTag(460): Check NDEF Failed - status = 255
08-14 17:20:36.559: D/NativeNfcTag(460): Check NDEF Failed - status = 255
08-14 17:20:36.680: D/NativeNfcTag(460): Check NDEF Failed - status = 255
08-14 17:20:36.700: D/NfcDispatcher(460): dispatch tag: TAG: Tech [android.nfc.tech.IsoDep, android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic, android.nfc.tech.NfcA, android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable] message: null
08-14 17:20:36.704: I/NfcDispatcher(460): matched TAG override
08-14 17:20:36.708: D/NfcDispatcher(460): Set Foreground Dispatch
08-14 17:20:36.735: W/System.err(5306): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Close other technology first!
08-14 17:20:36.735: W/System.err(5306):     at android.nfc.Tag.setConnectedTechnology(Tag.java:410)
08-14 17:20:36.735: W/System.err(5306):     at android.nfc.tech.BasicTagTechnology.connect(BasicTagTechnology.java:78)
08-14 17:20:36.735: W/System.err(5306):     at android.nfc.tech.IsoDep.connect(IsoDep.java:40)
08-14 17:20:36.739: W/System.err(5306):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnNewIntent(Instrumentation.java:1153)
08-14 17:20:36.739: W/System.err(5306):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverNewIntents(ActivityThread.java:2152)
08-14 17:20:36.739: W/System.err(5306):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performNewIntents(ActivityThread.java:2165)
08-14 17:20:36.739: W/System.err(5306):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleNewIntent(ActivityThread.java:2174)
08-14 17:20:36.739: W/System.err(5306):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:130)
08-14 17:20:36.739: W/System.err(5306):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1266)
08-14 17:20:36.739: W/System.err(5306):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-14 17:20:36.739: W/System.err(5306):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-14 17:20:36.739: W/System.err(5306):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-14 17:20:36.739: W/System.err(5306):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-14 17:20:36.743: W/System.err(5306):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-14 17:20:36.743: W/System.err(5306):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-14 17:20:36.743: W/System.err(5306):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-14 17:20:36.743: W/System.err(5306):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-14 17:20:36.747: D/NfcDispatcher(460): Set Foreground Dispatch
08-14 17:20:37.485: D/NativeNfcTag(460): Tag lost, restarting polling loop
08-14 17:20:40.626: D/AudioHardware(89): AudioHardware pcm playback is going to standby.
08-14 17:20:40.626: D/AudioHardware(89): closePcmOut_l() mPcmOpenCnt: 1
```

Comment: Do you get this error when trying to create a connection to the Java Card or do you get this exception when trying to create an RSA signature using the 2048 bit key?

Comment: it gets trying to create connection.but this issue is in there.http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/mobile/3aXNYCaZmG8/5sdbUnhZOT4J it happend when i try to select the application.

Comment: Have you called mfc.close() after you have read/written the card?